# Accessing Params in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, stripe-payments, railsapps

I am working through the RailsApps Stripe tutorial.

When a new subscriber is created through a `devise registration` controller they are then directed to their content page through a `content` controller. I want to use their `name` and `email address` created upon registration on their content page. But I can't seem to bring the params into the content controller.

I put`@user = User.find(params[:id])` into the `content_controller` but I get the error `"Couldn't find User without an ID".`

On the error page it lists under Request Info > rack session: `"warden.user.user.key"=>["User", [2]`,

So does that mean that ID of User #2 is being passed to the `content_controller` but that I can't access it?

Comment: Give the content in `devise_registration_controller.rb` and `content_controller.rb` to see how you are redirecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I put@user = User.find(params[:id]) into the content_controller but I
> get the error "Couldn't find User without an ID".

This error means that `params[:id] = nil`, i.e., you are not passing `id` in the params hash when redirecting the user to `content page`.

**Possible Solutions:**

1. With `Devise` you get a helper method called `current_user` which returns an instance of currently logged in user. So, you could directly use `current_user` to access the attributes of currently logged in user.  For example:

   To access `name` and `email` fields of currently logged in user, all you need to do is

   ```
   current_user.name
   current_user.email
   ```
2. In `routes.rb`, pass the `id` of the currently logged in user via the route of `content` page as below:

   ```
   ##  Add :id dynamic segment to your content page route  
   get "content/:id", :to => "contents#action_name", :as  => "content_page"
   ```

   Since, I don't have the route details, you would need to modify the above route as per your requirement.

   Next, when redirecting the user to `content` page after `sign up` just pass the currently logged in user as below in `ApplicationController` method named `after_sign_up_path_for` (You need to override this Devise method if you want to redirect the user to a different route than the default `root path`):

   ```
   def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
     content_page_path(resource) ## Provide the path and pass resource to it
   end
   ```

Answer (score 0):

With Devise, you can access the currently logged in user via the `current_user` helper in your controller.

See documentation: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers